# Unhandled Exception error unresolved compilation

Tags: java

```
public void useSkill(Champion target, int skillIndex, boolean enemy) throws UtilitiesException {
    if (champSkills[skillIndex].getManaCost() > this.currentMana) {
        throw new RequirmentNotMetException("Not Enough mana");
    }
```

I would like to throw a `requirmentNotMetexception` (which `extends` the `utilitiesException`) with message "not enough mana".

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type UtilitiesException

    at eg.edu.guc.lol.game.champions.Tank.useSkill(Tank.java:27)
    at eg.edu.guc.lol.game.champions.asfasf.main(asfasf.java:33)
```

I want to use exceptions  to show the user that the champion has no mana instead of using an if/else statement checking the mana of the champion and printing not enough mana.

Comment: What's the problem? Show us the error message.

Comment: I was in the middle of answering this question when it was closed.  Basically, if your `useSkill()` method has the potential to throw a `UtilitiesException` then the method that calls it (`asfasf.main()`) needs to wrap `useSkill()` in a try/catch block.  The message `Unhandled exception type UtilitiesException` is telling you you need to explicitly handle this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useSkill` method looks fine. It declares the exception type in the throws clause of the method signature, so the problem is likely where this method is invoked. It looks to me like you're getting the error runtime, which might indicate that you have not recompiled all the classes using the Tank class after you have changed the signature. Still, you need to either catch the exception where you're using the `useSkill` method, or just pass it on by declaring those methods to throw that exception type as well.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody in the call stack has to handle the `RequirmentNotMetException`, or every method on the call stack has to declare that it throws the exception (or a parent), or the exception has to extend `RuntimeException`.  Evidently, your main method is not declared as throwing it, and I wouldn't expect it to.  So, check up the call chain, identify who should handle the exception, have that method handle it, and have everything in between declare itself as throwing it.

Answer (score -1):

Either you have not imported the UtilitieException or your UtilitiesException class has errors.